# Prove that if you have two sets of linearly independent vectors of equal size:

Tags: linear-algebra

Let X, Y be two linearly independent sets of vectors of V such that |X| = |Y|.
Prove that for every x ∈ X there is a y ∈ Y such that the set (X \ {x}) ∪ {y} is
linearly independent

My thought process, is that if you have a set of n-1 linearly independent vectors, they can only span at most n-1 dimensions, so there must exist one vector in y, which is not a linear combination of the n-1 vectors from x.

Comment: Do you mean $(X\setminus\{x\})\cup\{y\}$?

Comment: yes, sorry let me change that

Comment: Your reasoning sounds right!

Comment: I think a little more detail is necessary. The argument certainly fails for an arbitrary set of vectors $Y$, so somewhere we have to use the fact that $Y$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Hint: assume the contrary.  Then each element of $Y$ would be in the span of $n-1$ vectors of $X$.